# Apply function to every element of list regardless of depth

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I want to apply a function to every element of a list without taking braces into account (depth level), but with the same form of output.

Here is an example :

```
{a,b,{c,d},{{e}}} -> {f[a],f[b],{f[c],f[d]},{{f[e]}}}
```

It would be the same as applying the function to `Flatten[data]`, but keeping the depth as is.

Let me know if I am not precise enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

molekyla777's answer can be very helpful but it is not technically correct.  The question specifies "every element of a **list**" but using a *levelspec* of `{-1}` will apply the function to every atomic element regardless of its head:

```
Map[f, 1 + 5 x + 10 x^2 + 10 x^3, {-1}]
```

> ```
> f[1] + f[5] f[x] + f[10] f[x]^f[2] + f[10] f[x]^f[3]
> ```

Of course this can be very useful but it is not what was requested.

To map to every `List` element we can use the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) attribute:

```
Function[a, f@a, Listable] @ {a, b, {c, d}, {{e}}, 1 + 10 x^3}
```

> ```
> {f[a], f[b], {f[c], f[d]}, {{f[e]}}, f[1 + 10 x^3]}
> ```

Note that the element `1 + 10 x^3` which I added is not subdivided.

You can also set the `Listable` attribute of `f` itself if it should always be applied this way:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
```

Now:

```
f @ {a, b, {c, d}, {{e}}, 1 + 10 x^3}
```

> ```
> {f[a], f[b], {f[c], f[d]}, {{f[e]}}, f[1 + 10 x^3]}
> ```

Be aware that if `f` is given multiple arguments it will [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html) as follows:

```
f[a, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {f[a, 1], f[a, 2], f[a, 3]}
> ```

```
f[{a, b, c}, {1, {2.1, 2.2}, 3}]
```

> ```
> {f[a, 1], {f[b, 2.1], f[b, 2.2]}, f[c, 3]}
> ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMHO. Love the use of `Listable` with pure function! (never realized that was even possible)

Comment: @seismatica I've known about Attribute of pure functions for a long time but the specific trick of using only its Listability is something recall learning from Rojo: [(3217)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8641)

Answer (score 16):

Use `Map` with a *levelspec* of `{-1}`:

```
Map[g, {a, b, {c, d}, {{e}}}, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {g[a],g[b],{g[c],g[d]},{{g[e]}}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had to do complicated codes to do this and I knew that there was a simple solution.