# Applying functions to leaves of nested list structure, when these leaves are more complex expression trees

Tags: expression-manipulation

Is there a way to apply a function h to the following nested list

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {{d, e }, {f, g}}}
```

where this should should become

> ```
> {h[a], h[c], {h[d], h[f]}}
> ```

`h` is applied to the first element of each (deepest nested) sublist, replacing this sublist. The nesting is never deeper than the example displayed above; i.e., the expression tree for the list has at most depth 3.

The rest of the list structure pattern is preserved.

Here, `a`, `c`, `d` and `f` are *not* atoms. They are again expressions with heads. The heads are however not list-heads.

As an example, consider

```
{{u[a], u[b]}, {u[v[c]], d}, {{d, e}, {f, g}}}
```

applying h to this should yield:

> ```
> {h[u[a]], h[u[v[c]]], {h[d], h[f]}}
> ```

In other words, h is applied to the "leaves" of the list expression given above, where these "leaves" are more complicated expressions.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56300/apply-function-to-every-element-of-list-regardless-of-depth -- the accepted answer (Mr. Wizard's) works for this case, and is virtually the same as mine below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Listable` attribute.  Give the attribute to `h` or a wrapper-function as below:

```
Module[{hh},
 SetAttributes[hh, Listable];
 hh[x__] := h[x];
 hh@{{u[a], u[b]}, {u[v[c]], d}, {{d, e}, {f, g}}}
 ]
(*  {{h[u[a]], h[u[b]]}, {h[u[v[c]]], h[d]}, {{h[d], h[e]}, {h[f], h[g]}}}  *)
```

Also:

```
Function[, h[##], Listable]@{{u[a], u[b]}, {u[v[c]], d}, {{d, e}, {f, g}}}
```

Comment: Strange. The expected output from the OP does not match your output, as he wanted the first element of a list to get wrapped in `h`, and the others to be dropped. Yet, he did accept this answer. So, I'm confused.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yeah, I missed that. Nobody said anything until now...

Comment: Ok, I realize that the first element was not kept, but the answer suited me best and the change is only minor.

Answer (score 5):

`ReplaceAll` with replacement rule `{x_, y : Except[___List]} :> h[x]`:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {{d, e}, {f, g}}} /. {x_, y : Except[___List]} :> h[x]
```

> {h[a], h[c], {h[d], h[f]}}

```
{{u[a], u[b]}, {u[v[c]], d}, {{d, e}, {f, g}}} /. {x_, y : Except[___List]} :> h[x]
```

> {h[u[a]], h[u[v[c]]], {h[d], h[f]}}

Comment: Happy 200K! That represents a lot of work and a lot of help given to others!

Comment: Thank you @Michael -- it has been a lot of fun.

Comment: Thanks! I like the Listable comment below and it seems that your solution works by excepting lists. A related question I wonder about is whether one can apply a function to any expression having a fixed type of head, but not to other expressions? It's a bit of a derail from the original topic, but the answers made me wonder about that aspect.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace) with a level of [`All`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/All):

```
Replace[
    {{a,b},{c,d},{{d,e},{f,g}}},
    {x:Except[_h],y:Except[_h]} :> h[x],
    All
]
```

> {h[a], h[c], {h[d], h[f]}}

Using [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace) with a level of [`All`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/All) does a depth first (bottom up) replacement. Using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll) instead uses a top down replacement:

```
ReplaceAll[
    {{a,b},{c,d},{{d,e},{f,g}}},
    {x:Except[_h],y:Except[_h]} :> h[x]
]
```

> {h[a], h[c], h[{d, e}]}

Comment: Not entirely sure this does the trick when a, b etc are not atoms, but expressions that are not lists. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Mike Do you mean an argument like `{{a, b}, {k[{c, l}], d}, {{d, e}, {f, g}}}`?

Comment: I mean arguments like: {{u[a], u[b]}, {u[v[c]], d}, {{d, e}, {f, g}}}